# See result of command design pattern when different objects call it

Tags: design-patterns, command

Let's say I want to open a door or two. When I open a door multiple things can happen. The door might open 90º, or 130º, or be blocked, or whatever.

On the other hand, I might want to open the door through a GUI or even through the command line.

So, when I do `Command openDoor = new OpenDoor(door)` and then do `openDoor.execute()` how do I know what the result of this operation was? If I simply needed to print to the console I could just print it. What if multiple actions happen throughout the command and I need to know their result as soon as they happen?

Again, if it's the console I can just print as it's happening. But on the GUI I can't. Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: Too broad a question. What is the return type of the openDoor.execute() method? Or does it cause events to be fired? What UI framework are you using? Question is just not answerable without such details

Comment: It's a broad question because the point of it is not being language dependent. The command design pattern says that the execute() method is void, and doesn't return anything. Suppose the language is Java or C#

Comment: The Command Pattern does not say the `execute()` method must be `void`. The GoF simply shows an example where the method happens to be `void`. It describes this implementation as, "_the simplest form_" of the Command interface, and also says, "_A command can have a wide range of abilities._" Java includes two standard implementations of the Command interface: [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) and [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html).